# set snapshot options from visual studio

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am now working on a project of about 25+ reports and I am getting bigtime weary setting all the caching/snapshot / processing options per report in the Report Manager...
Is it possible to set processing / snapshot / caching options from for example Visual Studio 2010? Is there any tooling that can automate this process?

I am looking for options to set these options for a range of reports.....
Does anyone knpow of any tooling / tips / tricks that might help me to alleviate this task?

Thanx for thinking withg me!

Henro

Comment: In the database for reporting services, there are tables that store this data, including cache schedules, cache policies and the Snapshot Data itself. There are also SQL Agent jobs created. In theory you could load all this data yourself including generating the GUIDs, but I've not heard of it being done. It would be so much work that you'd be better of using a .NET web application to display reports and use your own automated caching in that.

Comment: davos: do you know of such tools / software?

Comment: 25 reports is not that many, but I see your point in that managing all of that could get tedious. Mike's suggestion to use the web services interface is the best bet. 

I manage more than 250 reports presently and only about 20 of them use caching. The only reasons to use caching and snapshot the data are if reports run really slowly, or if the queries make a big performance impact on the source database. If you report directly from an operations database then that's a problem, but if it's a datawarehouse then it's not. I'm concerned you are caching all of the reports when you may not need to

Comment: Davos: I am only caching those that really need to be cached, because of performance. Even thoug they do run on a DWH, they are slow (due to excessive grouping and such). I am working on side too, but was hoping for a quick solution using the caching. ('till the rootcause is tackled)

Comment: Sounds like some indexes on the DWH might help there. If you're working on that then that's a long term solution. If caching is a temporary solution then automating caching is then not a priority. The danger is that cached reports might have queries that don't scale well and so get slower over time. You won't even notice if you're not monitoring the execution times, and before you know it those reports are taking hours to run and causing all sorts of problems. Sorry I don't know of any tools, and you probably know what I'm saying here already.

Comment: I am working on the indexes, that is through. Oh well, we just have to live with the slow reports until we tuned the whole shebang :) Thank you very much for your advice and consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Reporting Services Web Service Methods, ref:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx

E.g. SetCacheOptions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.setcacheoptions.aspx

I wouldn't advise hacking the Reporting Services database.

Comment: You do not happen to know of a tool that already can do this? I prefer not to bother my developers to create something that already exists, they are busy enough as it is...

Comment: No I havent come across any.

Comment: I dove in the world of powershell and I did it ;) Using your link.